# Spring Data JPA - Java 8 Stream Support & Transactional Best Practices

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I have a pretty standard MVC setup with Spring Data JPA Repositories for my DAO layer, a Service layer that handles Transactional concerns and implements business logic, and a view layer that has some lovely REST-based JSON endpoints.

My question is around wholesale adoption of Java 8 `Stream`s into this lovely architecture: If all of my DAOs return `Stream`s, my Services return those same `Stream`s (but do the Transactional work), and my Views act on and process those `Stream`s, then by the time my Views begin working on the Model objects inside my `Stream`s, the transaction created by the Service layer will have been closed. If the underlying data store hasn't yet materialized all of my model objects (it is a `Stream` after all, as lazy as possible) then my Views will get errors trying to access new results outside of a transaction. Previously this wasn't a problem because I would fully materialize results into a List - but now we're in the brave new world of `Stream`s.

So, what is the best way to handle this? Fully materialize the results inside of the Service layer as a List and hand them back? Have the View layer hand the Service layer a completion block so further processing can be done inside of a transaction?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In thinking through this, I decided to try the completion block solution I mentioned in my question. All of my service methods now have as their final parameter a results transformer that takes the Stream of Model objects and transforms it into whatever resulting type is needed/requested by the View layer. I'm pleased to report it works like a charm and has some nice side-effects.

Here's my Service base class:

```
public class ReadOnlyServiceImpl<MODEL extends AbstractSyncableEntity, DAO extends AbstractSyncableDAO<MODEL>> implements ReadOnlyService<MODEL> {

    @Autowired
    protected DAO entityDAO;

    protected <S> S resultsTransformer(Supplier<Stream<MODEL>> resultsSupplier, Function<Stream<MODEL>, S> resultsTransform) {
        try (Stream<MODEL> results = resultsSupplier.get()) {
            return resultsTransform.apply(results);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public <S> S getAll(Function<Stream<MODEL>, S> resultsTransform) {
        return resultsTransformer(entityDAO::findAll, resultsTransform);
    }

}
```

The `resultsTransformer` method here is a gentle reminder for subclasses to not forget about the try-with-resources pattern.

And here is an example Controller calling in to the service base class:

```
public abstract class AbstractReadOnlyController<MODEL extends AbstractSyncableEntity, 
                                                 DTO extends AbstractSyncableDTOV2, 
                                                 SERVICE extends ReadOnlyService<MODEL>> 
{

    @Autowired
    protected SERVICE entityService;

    protected Function<MODEL, DTO> modelToDTO;

    protected AbstractReadOnlyController(Function<MODEL, DTO> modelToDTO) {
        this.modelToDTO = modelToDTO;
    }

    protected List<DTO> modelStreamToDTOList(Stream<MODEL> s) {
        return s.map(modelToDTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    // Read All
    protected List<DTO> getAll(Optional<String> lastUpdate) 
    {
        if (!lastUpdate.isPresent()) {
            return entityService.getAll(this::modelStreamToDTOList);
        } else {
            Date since = new TimeUtility(lastUpdate.get()).getTime();
            return entityService.getAllUpdatedSince(since, this::modelStreamToDTOList);
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's a pretty neat use of generics to have the Controllers dictate the return type of the Services via the Java 8 lambda's. While it's strange for me to see the Controller directly returning the result of a Service call, I do appreciate how tight and expressive this code is.

I'd say this is a net positive for attempting a wholesale switch to Java 8 Streams. Hopefully this helps someone with a similar question down the road.

Comment: Simply passing a transformer function to the service is a marvelous idea. I was in the same pickle and trying to delay the transaction but your idea fits elegantly.